# I am using Sanity.io and came across this error in the database...Encountered a field that is not defined in the schema

Tags: reactjs, sanity

**This is my data.js file where I have mentioned all the queries**

```
export const userQuery = (userId) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "user" && _id == '${userId}']`;

    return query;
}

export const searchQuery = (searchTerm) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "pin" && title match '${searchTerm}*' || category match '${searchTerm}*' || about match '${searchTerm}*']{
        image{
            asset -> {
                url
            }
        },
        _id
        destination,
        postedBy -> {
            _id,
            userName,
            image
        },
        save[] {
            _key,
            postedBy -> {
                _id,
                userName,
                image
            },
        },
    }`
    return query;
}

export const feedQuery = `*[_type == "pin"] | order(_createAt desc) {
    image{
      asset->{
        url
      }
    },
        _id,
        destination,
        postedBy->{
          _id,
          userName,
          image
        },
        save[]{
          _key,
          postedBy->{
            _id,
            userName,
            image
          },
        },
      } `
```

This is where I have used these queries in my Pin.jsx file

```
<Link to={`user-profile/${postedBy?._id}`} className="flex gap-2 mt-2 items-center">
        <img
        className="w-8 h-8 rounded-full object-cover"
        src={postedBy?.image}
        alt="user-profile"
        />
        <p className="font-semibold capitalize">{postedBy?.userName}</p>

      </Link>
```

The complete error says this,

Unknown field found
Encountered a field that is not defined in the schema.

Developer info
This field is not defined in the schema, which could mean that the field definition has been removed or that someone else has added it to their own local project and have not deployed their changes yet.

I am not sure about how to go about this,
Due to this my userName and profile image which I get through Google login aren't getting fetch

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have posted the query but you are getting errors about the schema. You should post the schema.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a typo with how you are generating the postedBy reference.